# How best to use traits vs enums when describing a chess board

Tags: rust, enums

So, I'm trying to make a chess engine to brush up on my rust a bit, I'm generally a C# programmer.

In C#, for my data representation, I'd have something like:

```cs
public abstract class Piece 
{
   public Coordinate Location;
   
   public abstract bool IsWhite {get;}
   public abstract string PieceCode {get;} // e.g. K for a king

   public abstract Move[] GetPossibleMoves(Board board);
}

public sealed class Pawn:Piece {//etc...}
```

And then my board would have an array of all of the pieces to work with.

I believe, in Rust, something like this would be a good case for applying the more advanced enums, so something like this:

```rust
struct  Piece {
    position: Coordinate,
    isWhite: bool,
    charCode: char
}

enum PieceType {
    King(Piece),
    Queen(Piece),
    Bishop(Piece),
    Knight(Piece),
    Rook(Piece),
    Pawn(Piece)
}
```

But then I'm not really sure where I should put my implementation for getting the possible moves. Each `Piece` instance has no idea what type it is, and adding the `PieceType` enum to the `Piece` struct sort of feels like the antithesis of what this sort of structure is trying to achieve.

I suppose I could have a `Board` struct with a `Vec<PieceType>` and that has a method along the lines of `GetMovesFor(PieceType)` with a switch in it? At that point though, it feels like that one method would be doing far more than one job, it would have the implementation details for each piece rather than for just one as in how I'd structure it with C#.

Another alternative, is that I could go down a very similar route to that I'd take in C# and just us a `Piece` trait, implement that on each type and give my board a `Vec<Piece>`. At that point though, I feel like I'm just trying to emulate polymorphism rather than doing things the rustic way.

So I feel like I'm either misunderstanding what the goal of these extended enums is, and this isn't actually how to use them. Or, I'm missing some implementation detail.

Answers that could address either of these points would be grand!

Comment: The assumption that each piece (or pawn) has a coordinate is misguided, since pieces can be captured and may land off the board without a coordinate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the simplest possible model is usually the best, which would be that a piece has a color and a kind, which can both be represented as enums without a payload.  I think you're getting a bit lost trying to give your enums a payload when they don't really require one.

```
pub struct Piece {
    pub kind: PieceKind,
    pub color: PieceColor,
}

pub enum PieceKind {
    Pawn,
    Knight,
    Bishop,
    Rook,
    Queen,
    King,
}

pub enum PieceColor {
    White,
    Black,
}
```

A board would just be an 8x8 array of `Piece`s plus some additional information required to determine legality of castling and en passant moves:

```
pub struct Board {
    pub pieces: [[Option<Piece>; 8]; 8],

    pub white_can_castle_a: bool,
    pub white_can_castle_h: bool,
    pub black_can_castle_a: bool,
    pub black_can_castle_h: bool,

    // Some if the last piece moved was a pawn that was moved two spaces;
    // contains the coordinates to check for a valid en passant capture.
    pub last_double_pawn_move: Option<(usize, usize)>,
}
```

With this model you have all of the information you need to produce a list of valid moves for any piece.

Note that pieces don't have position data here; the position of a piece is determined by its location in the board.  In my opinion, your desire to have "get possible moves" be an operation that primarily exists on a *piece* is incorrect.  You need information about the entire board to determine this, which is revealed in your model by having this method accept `Board`.  I would model this as a method on `Board` that accepts an x,y coordinate pair instead.

```
// This type could use more members to be able to annotate special
// moves like castling.
struct Move {
    from: (usize, usize),
    to: (usize, usize),
}

impl Board {
    pub fn get_legal_moves_for(&self, piece: (usize, usize)) -> Vec<Move> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

I think part of your confusion is that you're trying to design the model using traits to be polymorphic over each kind of piece.  While trait-based polymorphism is fine and dandy, in this kind of model it would require dynamic dispatch and heap allocation (something that just *happens* in Java) while Rust can use a more efficient memory layout.  There is nothing wrong with `match`-based polymorphism either -- in fact, that's exactly how the [`Either`](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/enum.Either.html) type implements traits!

Comment: You might even go further here with an `enum` for `CastleOptions`, then `pub castle : (CastleOptions,CastleOptions)` where white = `.0`, black = `.1`. An `enum` lends itself to being a little state machine.

Comment: @tadman You could, but these flags are often individually set/inspected so cramming them into a single enum (None, Kingside, Queenside, Both) I think inhibits their usefulness without writing a bunch of extra boilerplate. E.g. you read a single flag to determine if a particular castling move is legal, and you set only one when a white rook is moved from a1 or h1, or a black rook is moved from a8 or h8. Perhaps such an enum could be useful to consumers of `Board` and so it could be returned from a public method, though.

Comment: That's a good point, but evolving this architecturally you could implement a `MoveRestriction` trait that can then be applied there as well, where each piece has one, and the castle option is a restriction as well. Then to check if a move is valid, just call each of these until an objection is raised, and if no such objection is made, then the move must be valid.

Comment: Iterating over each square, you could trivially test if any given move is valid as well, so it's pretty extensible.

Comment: @tadman If `CastleOptions` were a struct instead of an enum (`struct CastleOptions { a: bool, h: bool }`) then I could definitely be on board with that. My primary objection to an enum is that it hampers testing individual sides without a kind of silly `matches!()` invocation. Modeling it as a struct eliminates my objection to the idea. If memory efficiency is the concern, internally it could be implemented as a bitfield.

Comment: So I see your point here, but I don't think this addresses my concern with having `get_legal_moves_for` doing too much. Perhaps we could have each piece render its valid movement vectors? Then have the board level determine which are legal?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater That is one way to do it, though it makes optimization substantially more difficult.

Comment: I think the `Board` struct should also contain the active player if you want all information to find valid moves in one place. And maybe the half-move clock, so you know when the 50-move rule kicks in.

Comment: I've done things along this line in JavaScript decades ago and it ran just fine even then, so I'm confident that Rust can handle it even more easily. Doing a brute force check of the entire board (64 squares) for all pieces (16) is an entirely manageable number of calls, especially if these calls are really quick. There's no huge data structures here or complex algorithms. It's all basically constant-time.

Comment: So while I've accepted this answer, I've been mulling it over and what about an enum BoardState { Empty, King(Colour), Queen(Colour)... }? Then Board has an 8x8 array of that enum. No need for a Piece struct then

Comment: @ScottishTapWater That's inconvenient. You want to be able to access the colour of a piece independent of what kind of piece it is, e.g. to determine whether a piece can be captured.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - This is true

Comment: @ScottishTapWater The best way to explain why that enum is a bad idea is that the payload feature of enums is intended to be used _when the payload can differ for each variant._ In your case, it's always the same thing (color) which makes a struct more appropriate. For a counterexample, consider the built-in `Result<T, E>` enum, where the `Ok` variant has a `T` and the `Err` variant has an `E`. Or the built-in `IpAddr` enum, which can contain either an IPv4 or IPv6 address.